# How many experiments are required to observe all the states of a system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics

In an ensemble of systems, suppose each system may exist in $n$ states $\psi_i, i =1,2,3,\cdots ,n$ with an associated probability $P(\psi_i)$, respectively, $\sum_{i} P(\psi_i) = 1$. How many systems do we need to make the observation on, in order to observe each state of the system at least once.

### My approach

Let's do this numerically.

**Assumption:** $P(\psi_i) = \dfrac{1}{n}$; all states are equally likey to be observed.

#### Summary

I have an ensemble of identical systems from which I will be picking systems one-by-one and observing the state until I have observed all the states, and I will repeat this many times for each value of $n=1,2,\cdots,15$, then I will find the mean $\text{E}[X]$ and variance $\text{var}[X]$ of the number of systems I had to observe in order to observe all states $X$ and plot it. The setup of the numerical simulation is as follows:

[image: flowchart of simulation]

The mean $\text{E}[X]$ and variance $\text{var}[X]$ of the number of systems required to observe all the states $X$ depends on the number of states $n$. I did the simulation for $n = 1,2,3,\cdots,15$ making about $n^4$ observations each time.

#### Simulation

I ran the simulation in python3.7 and here is the code:

```
from random import randint
from statistics import mean, variance

N = []
E = []
V = []

for n in range(1,15):
    S = set([i for i in range(1,n+1)])
    X = []
    for m in range (1,pow(n,4)+2):
        x = 0
        R = set()
        while not S == R:
            x += 1
            R = R.union(set([randint(1,n)]))
            continue
        X += [x]
        continue
    N += [n]
    E += [mean(X)]
    V += [variance(X)]
    continue

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(N,E)
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('E[X]')
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(N,V)
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('var[X]')
plt.show()
```

### Results

The results of the numerical simulation are as follows:

[image: expected number of observations required for observing all the states of the system]

[image: variance of number of observations required for observing all the states of the system]

#### Inferences

The expected number of observations for observing $n=1,2,\cdots,14$ states varies almost linearly with $n$ with slope between $2$ and $4$. The variance, though, increases pretty rapidly, about as $n^3$ or $n^2$.

### Questions

First of all, the variance is really large for larger number of states of the system. Is the simulation correct? Also, can someone help me prove these results in a rigorous manner? For any value of $n$ and any distribution $P(\psi_{i})$, using some statistics or probability, perhaps.

Comment: While I don't have an answer for your query, https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2399-6528/ac96cf/pdf Perhaps the above mention of Leslie Ballentine might address part of your question. Hopefully another commenter will provide a better answer. I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: You may get more answers to questions like these at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: FYI: those `continue` statements in your code are completely superfluous. Additionally, using `+=` to add an element is necessarily slower than using `.append()` as `+=` creates a whole new list while append simply adds a new element to the back.

Answer (score 9):

This is known as the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). The name comes from the scenario of an advertising campaign giving you a prize if you collect the full set of $N$ coupons that are found in e.g. cornflakes packets. The coupons are randomly distributed between packets, and on average one needs to collect $O(N \log (N))$ packets to win. The variance grows as $O(N^2)$.

Comment: This is for the case where all "coupons" are equally likely, no? Do you know any result for more general probability distributions?

Comment: In general there doesn't seem to be any neat analytical approach (c.f.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3474643/coupon-collectors-variation-with-unequal-probabilities-and-uneven-number-of-ite ) and numerical Monte Carlo or solving as eigenvalue problems in Markov chains seem to be the only options.

Comment: The generalization appears to be listed on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations (see "In the general case of a nonuniform..."), with a citation to a paper that covers it in greater depth.  See also https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v15i1n31/pdf.